# Pass angular component function to javascript function - boxfactura

Tags: javascript, angular

I am implementing [this](https://www.boxfactura.com/pulltorefresh.js/) feature in my angular code to pull to refresh data and its pretty straightforward.

```
const ptr = PullToRefresh.init({
  mainElement: 'div.custom-div'
   onRefresh() {
     this.getData();
   }
});
```

and i have a function in my component called getData()

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {}

ngOnInit(): void {

const ptr = PullToRefresh.init({
  mainElement: 'div.custom-div'
   onRefresh() {
     this.getData();
   }
});

}

getData() {
  // get data function
}
}
```

but I'm having a hard time calling that from the javascript function. It throws the error

```
getData is not a function
```

and I know it does this because it reads this as the js function instead of the component it is embedded in. How can i go about this correctly?

Comment: What is `this`? Where is `getData` defined?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it is defined in the angular component

Comment: What angular component? May you share that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have updated

Comment: It looks like you have a syntax error.

Comment: there's no error. the function works when called outside of the javascript code

Comment: Please may you update the example then? It has a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    
    constructor() {}
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
    const This = this;
    const ptr = PullToRefresh.init({
      mainElement: 'div.custom-div'
       onRefresh() {
         This.getData();
       }
    });
    
    }
    
    getData() {
      // get data function
    }
 }
```